# How to sort a List of strings by multiple conditions

Tags: c#, list, if-statement, foreach

I have a List of strings that looks like this (completely unsorted):

```
[Title b] \t [text] \t complete
[Title a] \t [text] \t incomplete
[Title a] \t [text] \t complete
[Title c] \t [text] \t complete
...
```

It shall be sorted to look like either this:

```
[Title a] \t [text] \t complete
[Title a] \t [text] \t incomplete
[Title b] \t [text] \t complete
[Title c] \t [text] \t complete
...
```

Or this (which way it shall be sorted is selectable)

```
[Title a] \t [text] \t complete
[Title j] \t [text] \t complete
[Title s] \t [text] \t complete
...

[Title b] \t [text] \t incomplete
...
```

My approach on this whole sorting thing is kinda dirty and not sleek at all and also only solves the second way of sorting.

```
List<string> sortedTps = new List<string>();
List<string> completeTps = new List<string>();
List<string> incompleteTps = new List<string>();
List<string> errorTps = new List<string>();

foreach (string tp in tpByProduct)
{
    if (tp.Contains("\t complete"))
    {
        completeTps.Add(tp);
    }
    else if (tp.Contains("\t incomplete"))
    {
        incompleteTps.Add(tp);
    }
 }

 completeTps.Sort();
 incompleteTps.Sort();

 foreach(string tp in completeTps)
 {
    sortedTps.Add(tp);
 }

 foreach(string tp in incompleteTps)
 {
    sortedTps.Add(tp);
 }
```

Hope you guys can show me how to do this better and shorter ^^

Comment: You can write your own comparer for that. Can you share the exact rules of sorting? What is the `errorTps`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Code you posted can be done with LINQ:

```
var sortedTps = tpByProduct.OrderBy(x => x.Contains("\t complete")).ThenBy(x => x).ToList();
```

First it will sort after whether the string contains "\t complete", then it will sort after the string itself. In the end, the sorted result ist copied into a new list.

Comment: His code example ain't complete, but in his question he explains that the sorting should be configurable. First on title then complete, or first on complete then on title. This is not the case in your solution.